# Demon's Souls: I keep dying

Tags: demons-souls

In Demon's Souls, I keep dying. I gave up on the game eventually, but it's really addicting. I try to gather souls, but when I upgrade my character, I feel no change. I know it's really hard, but how can I get past 1-2? A dragon keeps killing me. My class is a Knight, and I use a club and a long sword with a soldier's shield. (Kite shield broke.)

Comment: The blacksmith in the Nexus can repair your items, including your broken shield.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get past the dragon on the bridge in 1-2, you simply have to run. Wait near the start of the bridge where it's safe. Then, as soon as the dragon has breathed fire on the bridge, run to the other side (hold the circle button to sprint). Don't be distracted by the items.

Also, try to prioritize spending souls on weapon upgrades rather than stats. Stats help, but upgrading your weapon tends to help more.

If you're still having trouble, you can always try one of the other archstones. You don't have to do them in order.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is for any class and for anyone who is struggling with this demonic game (initially poorly developed - that's why it's so hard - but that defined a new genre itself):

- no matter what **class** your chose, a good way to start is **being a fighter**. That means: use an one handed weapon and a shield;
- learn to keep your shield up **all the time**;
- observe the enemies and **learn** how they move/attack. Also try to discover which type of weapon does more **damage** on each enemy;
- after you have defeated the first boss in 1-1 (World 1, Part 1 - the Boletarian Palace), try the other worlds and see if there is one **where you fight better**. Then repeat that to get more souls;
- everytime you go back to the Nexus, try to use all your souls with **upgrading your stats**. (Just don't forget to repair your equipment first.) And don't forget to use the items ("souls") you collect from fallen heroes to obtain more souls, but don't use the souls from the bosses: they serve as ingredients to get special items from NPCs;
- about **stats**, **Endurance** is every class' friend, as it determines your Stamina (that you use to **run** and to **block attacks**). Then try to focus on those stats that enhance the damage specific to your class;
- **don't buy** equipments, unless the one you have are completely broken / lost;
- use bows and magic for distant enemies (and that only). **Keep your distance** and run! - or learn to switch weapons (to melee) to adapt to the battle;
- and in doubt, consult the game wiki: http://demonssouls.wikidot.com. Again, this is a poorly developed game, and you **there are many things you will never know without looking outside the game**.

**Specifically on 1-2, you have to track the dragon movements and timing so you can run after he flies by. You can also travel through the bridge underground / tunnels in some parts.**

Good luck!

Comment: Did pretty well for a 'poorly developed game'.